# Удалить последние сообщение Telegram отправленное ботом (Python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

````
```async def main_menu(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы вернулись в "↩ Главное меню"', reply_markup=client_keyboard)```
````

При возврате в главное меню я хочу вывести клавиатуру client_keyboard. У меня всё получается, я её вывожу. Но вместе с клавиатурой выводится и сообщение 'Вы вернулись в "↩ Главное меню"'. Я бы не хотел выводить это сообщение, хочу просто поменять меню.

Вопрос: Я могу отправить просто клавиатуру без сообщения? Или, я могу отправить сообщение с клавиатурой и сразу удалить это сообщение?

Comment: А какая именно клавиатура? reply или inline?

Comment: В данном случаи reply (нижняя).

Comment: Ну удалить его вы не можете, так как с ним пропадет и клавиатура. А вообще рекомендую перейти на инлайн кнопки, их можно красиво редактировать без изменения текста, в отличие от реплай. Попробуйте вывести просто "_" или какой-нибудь почти пустой текст, как вариант.